# How to access parent overridden function from parent's class scope in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, super

#### MCVE

I have written this MCVE to illustrate my question and simplify it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "Aaaa"
        print(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.a)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "Bbbb"
        super().__init__()
        print(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.b)
```

I use inheritance and I want to log each `__init__` method to keep track of created objects (emulated by `print`). I also needs to call `super().__init__()` method because I need to initialize parent class in different contexts.

#### Actual and expected

When I create a `B()` object, I get:

```
b = B()
# Bbbb
# Bbbb
```

I expected:

```
# Aaaa
# Bbbb
```

How can I make `A` part of the class when used with inheritance by creating a `B` instance using it own `A.__str__()` function instead of the `B.__str__()` overridden function?

#### How to deal with MRO?

As far as I understand it, it seems it will always use the `B.__str__()` method because the Method Resolution Order in this case is about:

```
b.__class__.mro()
# [__main__.B, __main__.A, object]
```

I know that I can print `Aaaa` from `B.__init__()` using `super().__str__()`.

But it is the converse I want to do here. I want to call `A.__str__()` of a `B` object when its `A.__init__()` is executed.

Is there any clean way to do it with Python?

Comment: The straightforward answer is that ``A.__str__(self)`` will always format ``self`` as if it were an ``A``, so just call the method you want. The counter question however is, what are you trying to achieve here? Why don't you just ``print("Aaaa")``or ``print(A)``? Why do you feel it is necessary to log this in the first place? Can every subclass even be represented as the base class?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, thank you for recalling me `A.__str__(self)`, it indeed worked. I am not sure I have got the sense of your question, could you elaborate a bit please. This MCVE is really far from what I am building, I may have left some misleading "Aaaa" when designing it to reproduce my problem.

Comment: What is your goal in doing all of this? Initialisation is usually an implementation detail, and deep inheritance hierarchies are frowned upon. Basically, why is your inheritance so complicated that it needs logging? Why is logging only appropriate with the full object information, instead of just the class? Are you doing this just for you own learning experience, to see how inheritance works?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I want to log details of creation of this part of the object for debugging purposes. Because many object inherits from it, I found useful to make this check there (seemed natural to me) instead of checking it in all class. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Since I do not know what you are actually doing, I cannot say whether it is wrong or not. Personally, I feel an initialiser should not be as complex as to need logging. Logging is usually used for active parts, e.g. handling requests or interacting with a DB, which depend on consistency of runtime data often provided by users. An initialiser should do no such thing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Thank you for your advice, now I do understand your point. I may be a bit overlogging indeed, I feel convenient to have it even at initialization state and I confess it is a bit verbose and maybe not totally relevant in many cases.